# Login failed for user 'sa' only on Azure Pipelines

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run e2e test in my azure pipeline. But the services fail to start correctly because they cannot connect to the sql with following error:

```
 Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7
 Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 172.18.0.9]
```

The confusing part is, it only fails on the azure pipeline. On my local machine it works without any problems.
I already tried different passwords and connection strings. I run a linux container on azure pipelines and on my machine as well.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  sqldata:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

  identity-api:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-PROJECTNAME}/identity.api:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  sqldata:
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "5433:1433"

  identity-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
      - ConnectionString=Server=sqldata;Database=IdentityDb;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that the database was still starting when the service tried to connect and run the migrations. I added a check to wait for the master db to be ready before the service does it's migrations.

```
while (IsServerConnected(connectionString) == false)
{
    logger.LogWarning("Database server not ready ({ConnectionString})...", connectionString);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
...
private static bool IsServerConnected(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```